# MetadataObjectNotFoundExceptionState when creating an external content type in SharePoint Designer

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, bcs, wcf, wsdl

I am getting a really strange error in SharePoint designer upon trying to create an external content type for a simple SOAP Web service.

The error happens at the moment I clicked **Add Connection**, have filled out the data source connection details and clicked **OK**

More exactly, the error message in SPD is not really descriptive (something like it was not able to load WSDL), but if I capture the traffic with Fiddler, I can see this:

```
<MetadataException i:type="a:MetadataObjectNotFoundExceptionState" xmlns="Microsoft.BusinessData.SharePoint" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:a="Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData">
<explicitMessage>false</explicitMessage>
<innerExceptionToStringed i:nil="true"/>
<innerExceptionTypeFullName i:nil="true"/>
<message>IEntity could not be found using criteria 'The requested Entity 'Account List' under Namespace 'http://...' was not found.'.</message>
<metadataObjectTypeName>Microsoft.BusinessData.MetadataModel.IEntity, Microsoft.BusinessData, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</metadataObjectTypeName>
<serverStackTrace>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.SharedService.BdcServiceApplicationProxy.Execute[T](String operationName, UInt32 maxRunningTime, ExecuteDelegate`1 operation, Boolean performCanaryCheck, Boolean isChannelThatDelegatesIdentity)&#xD;
at Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.SharedService.BdcServiceApplicationProxy.GetEntityWithNameAndNamespace(String namespace, String name, Guid partitionId)&#xD;
```

(namespace omitted for privacy reasons)

If I take a look at [the MSDN page for GetEntityWithNameAndNamespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd960262%28v=office.12%29.aspx), I can see that

> The GetEntityWithNameAndNamespace operation retrieves the active Entity with the specified name and namespace in the specified partition.

But I am not really sure why SharePoint Designer expects to retrieve any entities for an external content type that has not even been created yet?

What I can also see from the Fiddler capture is that the failing GetEntityWithNameAndNamespace operations (there are several ones, by the way) are consistently preceded with attempt to create an AdministrationMetadataCatalogStruct:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
<MetadataObjectCreate xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/Office/2009/BusinessDataCatalog">
<rawValues i:type="a:AdministrationMetadataCatalogStruct"
xmlns:a="Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData" 
xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<a:id>0</a:id><a:isCached>true</a:isCached>
<a:name/><a:objectVersion>0</a:objectVersion>
<a:partitionId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</a:partitionId>
</rawValues>
<parentStruct i:nil="true" 
xmlns:a="Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData" 
xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
</MetadataObjectCreate>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I am pretty sure we're all set at the BCS side (permissions, target application in secure store etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a DNS name resolution issue (the Web service and the SharePoint farm belong to different domains on a corporate network)

Once DNS settings were fixed, the development configuration started working as expected.

However, the caveat with with the production config is that SharePoint Designer apparently cannot authenticate with a client SSL certificate so it fails to retrieve the web service's WSDL metadata :(